# Book recommendations about IEEE 802.11/WiFi on a beginners level

Tags: wifi

I'm looking for good books giving an introduction and overview to current WiFi standards at a beginner's level.

I found:

- *"Designing and Deploying 802.11 Wireless Networks"* by Jim Geier
- *"Wireless Networking Technology"* by Steve Rackley.

Does anyone one of you read this books and can recommend them or knows another similar literature?

Answer (score 1):

Answering an old but I hope still useful question. I had the same question and tried to find books. Ideally, you'll want a book that incorporates the latest standards. That would at the moment of writing this answer (2024) be at least 802.11ax or Wi-Fi 6, which has been approved in 2020. Wi-Fi 7 is expected to be ratified end of 2024.

You will also want to read about standards that help roaming and network management. These are 802.11k ("radio resource management", 2008), 802.11v ("network management" 2011) and 802.11r ("fast roaming", 2008).

This means that Steve Rackley's book, being from 2007, would simply be too outdated to be helpful. The Cisco Press book by Jim Geier could be helpful, but is still almost 10 years old and sees Wi-Fi 5 (802.11ac) as a new topic.

I also came across two books by Gordon Colbach; reviewers say that they are really too shallow on the subject: sometimes not more than a list of ratification dates of standards.

What looks promising is "**Enterprise Wireless Local Area Network Architectures and Technologies**". It's from 2021 and seems to have all the details: roaming, 802.11ax, enterprise network planning. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any reviews yet and the contents could be manufacturer/solution centric, as all the authors work for Huawei. I just don't know.